# difference between two columns in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want difference between two columns in the table 
    my table looks like below :

```
SecurityID      High        Low     
918         15405.00000 15180.00000 
918         15500.00000 15240.00000 
918         15690.00000 15425.00000
```

I want the table :

```
SecurityID      High        Low     difference
918         15405.00000 15180.00000 15405.00000-15180.00000=225.0000
918         15500.00000 15240.00000 15500.00000-15240.00000=260.0000
918         15690.00000 15425.00000 15690.00000-15425.00000=265.0000
```

please help me 
I want difference between two columns

Comment: So what's the problem? Why can't you just subtract them? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Use the minus (`-`) operator. It subtracts two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select
    SecurityID,
    High,
    Low,
    cast(High as varchar(25)) + '-' + cast(Low as varchar(25)) + ' = ' + cast(High - Low as varchar(25)) as Results 
From TableA
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be something like this :

```
 Select SecurityID, High,Low, (High-Low) AS difference FROM yourTable
```

You can know more about : [Arithmetic Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/arithmetic-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the answer to appear as a column in the table, as the question appears to ask I would create a computed column on the table.

Lets say the table is called fred.

You could achieve this by issuing the following alter table command...

```
alter table fred
add difference as cast(high as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast(low as varchar(10)) + '=' + cast(high - low as varchar(10));
```

This would add a computed column called difference. There would be no value stored physically in this column on the table, instead SQL Server will calculate the value of that column, based on the formula and the other two values, each and every time you perform a select statement. (There will be a very slight performance overhead for this).

If, however,  you want the value to be persisted to the column, instead you can issue the following command instead.

```
alter table fred
add difference as cast(high as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast(low as varchar(10)) + '=' + cast(high - low as varchar(10)) persisted;
```

Instead of the value being calculated when a select command is issued, it will be calculated when either High or Low are updated. (No performance overhead at select, but a slightly higher one at insert or update instead).

More information on computed columns can be found at: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017